# Log considerations for high volume data

Tags: java, logging, scalability

I am working on a design to log high volume of data.The data can be of a typical size of around 1Kb-10Kb.Also what I mean by high volume is it can be up to 10000 data points per second.So if I consider worst case for every hour data can be logged as much as 10000*10*60*60B or 360Mb.I can use log rotation so that it doesn't cross a threshold.But what can be other alternatives to make this number go down even more.I can try compression but then I should give up on log readability.Or I can only maintain a metadata for each data.What other techniques can I try and what will be the pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem on a smart watch product few years back. Since the on device RAM was really low (typical for embedded systems) we resorted to the following techniques:-

1. **Save to file system** - Write the data to the persistent file system whenever size grows beyond a threshold - this can even be done based on time since you are saying you have a predictability relationship of log size with time
2. **Upload to Cloud** - If storage on device becomes a problem - you may as well consider posting the log data to a cloud server
3. **Optimize log data** - This can be tricky - try to log as less as possible per cycle - meaning define a format to capture just data points instead of text. This would mean interpretation of the logs have to have a little parser as well - that's the trade off you will have to consider
   Example consider this for a location based log:-
   *Lat:100.23; Lon:23.87; Height: 233; Time stamp: 1875340*
   This can well be reduced to:-
   [100.23,23.87,233,1875340]
   With such high volumes these small bits here and there will provide massive savings

All the best!